# Error while encrypting

Tags: apex, encryption

I am getting the below error while encrypting data.

> System.InvalidParameterValueException: Invalid private key. Must be 16 bytes.: Class.System.Crypto.encryptWithManagedIV: line 50, column 1

Here is my code,

```
trigger Account_Encrypt_Trigger on Account (before insert,before update) {
    //Blob cryptoKey = Crypto.generateAesKey(128);
    Blob PrivateKey = EncodingUtil.base64Decode('Secretkey');
    Blob data = Blob.valueOf('testuser');
    Blob encryptedData = Crypto.encryptWithManagedIV('AES128',PrivateKey,data);
    Blob decryptedData = Crypto.decryptWithManagedIV('AES128',PrivateKey, encryptedData);
    String EncryptedDataString = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(encryptedData);
    String decryptedDataString = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(decryptedData);
    //String EncryptedDataString = encryptedData.toString();
    //String decryptedDataString = decryptedData.toString();
    system.debug('This is encrypted data   '+ EncryptedDataString);
    system.debug('This is decrypted Data   '+ decryptedDataString);
}
```

Could someone please help me fix this issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check the Blob size that comes back from:

```
Blob PrivateKey = EncodingUtil.base64Decode('Secretkey');
```

It should be 16 bytes. With the sample code you have the length is only 6, but I suspect that is because you haven't put the actual key in the question.

In contrast, the following executes in anonymous apex:

```
Blob PrivateKey = Crypto.generateAesKey(128);
System.debug(PrivateKey.size());
System.assertEquals(16, PrivateKey.size());

Blob data = Blob.valueOf('testuser');
Blob encryptedData = Crypto.encryptWithManagedIV('AES128',PrivateKey,data);
Blob decryptedData = Crypto.decryptWithManagedIV('AES128',PrivateKey, encryptedData);
String EncryptedDataString = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(encryptedData);
String decryptedDataString = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(decryptedData);
//String EncryptedDataString = encryptedData.toString();
//String decryptedDataString = decryptedData.toString();
system.debug('This is encrypted data   '+ EncryptedDataString);
system.debug('This is decrypted Data   '+ decryptedDataString);
```

From the documentation for [encryptWithManagedIV](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.200.0.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_restful_crypto.htm#apex_System_Crypto_encryptWithManagedIV):

> The initialization vector is stored as the first 128 bits (16 bytes) of the encrypted Blob.

Comment: Blob PrivateKey = EncodingUtil.base64Decode('secrettoencrypt1'); . I use this as actual key, which is 16 char length. but system.assert counting it as 12 bytes. I am not sure how to fit inn this key in my code.

Comment: To get 16 bytes from a base64 encoded string the input string will need to be 24 characters long. E.g. `'1ZRqah8/mgDGetKXKOmE1g=='`. There is not a one-to-one mapping between the input characters and the output bytes with base64 encoding.

Comment: Daniel, is there any other way to use my secretkey and encrypt the data using AES.

Comment: You could pad it out until the length of the blob matches the required AES private key length. Basically you need 16 bytes (eq. 128 bits) for AES128. With n as the number of characters in the string key the byte length will be `n / 4 * 3`

Comment: Blob encryptedData = Crypto.encryptWithManagedIV('AES128',blob.valueOf('secrettoencrypt1'),data);
Blob decryptedData = Crypto.decryptWithManagedIV('AES128',blob.valueOf('secrettoencrypt1'),encryptedData);     I managed to find a way to use the same secretkey in the encryption function. But the output string is not matching output i receive out of java code.  If i pass my java code would be able to do code compare for me?